# Как найти число Фибоначчи с помощью рекурсии js... я просто не понимаю как цикл вставить в рекурсию чтобы он работал

Tags: javascript

```js
// вот цикл

var x = 0;
var y = 1;

for(var i=0; i<=10; i++)
{
    var z = x + y;
    console.log(z);
    x = y;
    y = z;
}
```

Comment: ```function fibonacci(num) {
  if (num <= 1) return 1;

  return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
}```

Comment: В рекурсии не должно быть цикла в принципе. В данном случае, то есть, когда Вы выполняете рекурсивный вызов функции, значения записываются в стек, а потом в обратном порядке происходит суммирование всех переменых и Вы получаете нужное число.

Comment: спасибо вам за помощь